# Swashbuckle Swagger - How to annotate content types?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

How do I annotate my ASP.NET WebAPI actions so that the swagger metadata includes the content-types that my resources support?

Specifically, I want the documentation to show that one of my resources can return the 'original' `application/json` and `application/xml` but also now returns a new format, `application/vnd.blah+json` or `+xml`.

Comment: Shashbuckle 5 should take care of this for you if you register the MediaTypeFormatter during the Web Api configuration.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds clever, but I want it per action/route.

Comment: I think you just need to add it as a formatter in your webconfig - this is global though, on not on a per action basis.
What you could do was create your own operationsFilter and apply it only to those operations that returns the new format

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you need to do is this;
**Swagger spec:**
you need to add your response-type to the list of response-types for that operation:

```js
"produces": [
            "application/json",
            "text/json"
            ],
```

This can be done with an OperationFilter.

**Pseudo Code incoming!!!**

```cs
public class CustomResponseType : IOperationFilter
{        
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {            
            if (operation.operationId == "myCustomName")
            {
                operation.produces.Add("application/vnd.blah+json");
            }            
    }      
}
```

the OperationId can be set through the `[SwaggerOperation("myCustomName")]` annotation.

Then apply the operationsFilter in the swaggerConfig.cs:

```cs
c.OperationFilter<CustomResponseType>();
```

Note:
instead of `operation.operationId == "myCustomName"`
you could do it for a particular route or anything else basically. ApiDescription gives a LOT of info about context.

Answer (score 50):

Extending [@VisualBean's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35129474).

On a Controller's API method, you could use the code below to set an Attribute like:

```cs
[SwaggerResponseContentType(responseType:"application/pdf", Exclusive=true)]
public HttpResponseMessage GetAuthorityForm(string id)
{
....
```

Note: 'Exclusive=true' will remove all other content types, otherwise using the new Attribute will add a new Response Content Type in the Swagger UI drop down.  It will NOT modify your Controller or API, just the documentation.

**SwaggerConfig.cs**

```cs
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
 // Set filter to apply Custom Content Types to operations
 //
 c.OperationFilter<ResponseContentTypeOperationFilter>();
```

**SwaggerResponseContentTypeAttribute.cs**

```cs
/// <summary>
/// SwaggerResponseContentTypeAttribute
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class SwaggerResponseContentTypeAttribute : Attribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// SwaggerResponseContentTypeAttribute
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="responseType"></param>
    public SwaggerResponseContentTypeAttribute(string responseType)
    {
        ResponseType = responseType;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Response Content Type
    /// </summary>
    public string ResponseType { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove all other Response Content Types
    /// </summary>
    public bool Exclusive { get; set; }
}
```

**ResponseContentTypeOperationFilter.cs**

```cs
public class ResponseContentTypeOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        var requestAttributes = apiDescription.GetControllerAndActionAttributes<SwaggerResponseContentTypeAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

        if (requestAttributes != null)
        {
            if (requestAttributes.Exclusive)
                operation.produces.Clear();

            operation.produces.Add(requestAttributes.ResponseType);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

[@OzBob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36348869) assumes you only want to add a single attribute to a method. If you want to add and document more than one content types for the same method, you can use the following:

**SwaggerResponseContentTypeAttribute.cs**

```cs
/// <summary>
/// SwaggerResponseContentTypeAttribute
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class SwaggerResponseContentTypeAttribute : Attribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// SwaggerResponseContentTypeAttribute
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="responseType"></param>
    public SwaggerResponseContentTypeAttribute(string responseType)
    {
        ResponseType = responseType;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Response Content Type
    /// </summary>
    public string ResponseType { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove all other Response Content Types
    /// </summary>
    public bool Exclusive { get; set; }
}
```

**ResponseContentTypeOperationFilter.cs**

```cs
public class ResponseContentTypeOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        var requestAttributes = apiDescription.GetControllerAndActionAttributes<SwaggerResponseContentTypeAttribute>();

        foreach (var requestAttribute in requestAttributes)
        {
            if (requestAttribute.Exclusive)
            {
                operation.produces.Clear();
            }
            operation.produces.Add(requestAttribute.ResponseType);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that when you have multiple attributes on the same method and you want to replace the existing content types, you should set `Exclusive = true` on the first attribute only. Otherwise, you won't get all the attributes into the documentation.

Comment: Having to put the Exclusive=true as the first attribute is not obvious for the developer. I think the order of the attributes shouldn't affect the output. Sorting the list of attributes in the filter should remove the limitation : requestAttributes.OrderByDescending(a=>a.Exclusive)

Answer (score 4):

Following on [OzBob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36348869). Since Swashbuckle 4.0.x, you may need to update the operation filter code slightly:

**ResponseContentTypeOperationFilter.cs**

```cs
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;
using System.Linq;

public class ResponseContentTypeOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ApiDescription.TryGetMethodInfo(out var methodInfo))
        {
            return;
        }
        var requestAttributes = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<SwaggerResponseContentTypeAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

        if (requestAttributes != null)
        {
            if (requestAttributes.Exclusive)
                operation.Produces.Clear();

            operation.Produces.Add(requestAttributes.ResponseType);
        }
    }
}
```