# swashbuckle mediatype application/octetstream

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

I have an endpoint that produces mediatype as application/octet-stream. However, when I generated the swagger json, it specifies "produces" as "application/json"
I did not do any special configs in swagger. All I did was import swagger nuget and just kept the default configuration as is. 
Please find below the endpoint:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("document/method1")]
    public HttpResponseMessage method1([FromBody]SomeModel SomeModelValue)
    {
        // code that generates the file
        if (File.Exists(outputFilePath))
        {
            byte[] resultFile = File.ReadAllBytes(outputFilePath);
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
            response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ResultFile);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue(ContentDispositionHeaderValue);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MediaTypeHeaderValue);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = ResultFile.Length;
            File.Delete(inputFilePath);
            File.Delete(outputFilePath);
            return response;
        }
        else
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }
```

And the jsonSchema from swagger:

```
"/document/method1": {
"post": {
    "tags": ["Document"],
    "operationId": "Document_Method1",
    "consumes": ["application/json", "text/json", "application/xml", "text/xml", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
    "produces": ["application/json", "text/json", "application/xml", "text/xml"],
    "parameters": [{
        "name": "SomeModelValue",
        "in": "body",
        "required": true,
        "schema": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/SomeModel"
        }
    }],
    "responses": {
        "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
                "type": "object"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It might be [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990291/swashbuckle-swagger-how-to-annotate-content-types)

Comment: Thanks so much Ivan for pointing me to the right post. Am sorry, I missed it and possibly duplicated the question. Thanks anyway. It helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a fork of swashbuckle that I have been adding functionality like what you are asking, now you can add Annotations like:

```
[SwaggerResponse(200, mediaType: "image/png")]
```

Here is a working sample:
http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index#/Image/Image_Get

My fork is on Nuget:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swagger-Net/